# ssh-keygen accepting stdin

Tags: linux, bash, variables, ssh-keys

I am trying to call `ssh-keygen` using a variable through `bash` as an input instead of a file to get a fingerprint of a public key.  I am aware that I could use a temp file to get around this issue, but for reasons out of scope of this question, I do not want to.

This method does *not* work as it says the key file is invalid (it's correct for sure)

```
echo $pubkey | ssh-keygen -lf /dev/stdin
```

This *does* work, but is not using a variable, rather a file.

```
ssh-keygen -lf alpha.pub
```

This *does* work, but is not using a variable, rather a redirected file.

```
ssh-keygen -lf /dev/stdin < alpha.pub
```

This does *not* work because I get an ambiguous redirect

```
ssh-keygen -lf /dev/stdin < $(echo $pubkey)
```

I would appreciate some insight as to how to get ssh-keygen to read from a variable with a public key and if possible, an explanation as to why the redirects aren't doing what I think they should be doing.  In specific why the `|` behaves differently than the `<` and why the third example is an `ambiguous redirect`.  I searched online but many of the redirect tutorials didn't seem to answer my questions.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
echo $pubkey | ssh-keygen -lf /dev/stdin
/dev/stdin is not a public key file.
```

/dev/stdin is actually a unix pipe, not a regular file, so ssh-keygen fails to open the file

```
ssh-keygen -lf /dev/stdin  <<<$key
1024 92:6a:3f:5c:1f:78:.....
```

/dev/stdin refers to a regular file, created by using a bash heredoc. You can verify this:

```
# ls -l /dev/stdin <<<$pubkey
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Feb 11 08:07 /dev/stdin -> /proc/self/fd/0
# ls -l /proc/self/fd/0 <<<$pubkey
lr-x------ 1 juergen juergen 64 Apr 14 13:31 /proc/self/fd/0 -> /tmp/sh-thd-1271250023 (deleted)
```

Comment: On Ubuntu 14.04, Bash 4.3.11, kernel 3.13.0-24-generic, this doesn't work and reports `/dev/stdin: Stale file handle`.

Answer (score 20):

Since version 7.2 (released on on 2016-02-28), this is now possible by passing `-` as the file name. [From the release notes:](http://www.openssh.com/txt/release-7.2)

> - ssh-keygen(1): allow fingerprinting from standard input, e.g. `ssh-keygen -lf -`

Comment: With the release of OpenSSH 7.2, this should now be the accepted answer. So `echo $pubkey | ssh-keygen -lf -`, or the like, is the way to go now.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a one liner using the file `/dev/stdin` as described in other answers.

```
$ ssh-keygen -lf /dev/stdin <<< $( ssh-keygen -f ~/.ssh/keyname.pem -y )
2048 14:df:c7:b7:f1:26:7f:87:d5:e7:10:6c:ac:af:a2:03 /dev/stdin (RSA)
```

Note that this will break with private keys that use a passphrase. It will work with pem files generated by AWS or OpenStack which do not use passphrases.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to redirect a string as stdin, use this syntax:

```
cmd <<< "some $STR here"
```

If you want to redirect the output of a command as if it was a file, you do it like this:

```
cmd <( /bin/somecmd )
```

And if you want to use a command as an OUTPUT file, it's more or less the same:

```
cmd >( /bin/othercmd )
```

Comment: So `ssh-keygen -lf /dev/stdin <<< "$pubkey"` will probably do what the OP wants then.

Comment: `ssh-keygen -lf /dev/stdin <<<"$(memento show)"` worked for me

Answer (score -2):

I would recommend using a temporary file.  The issue is that redirecting, BASH expects a file.  By using $(echo $pubkey), bash will complain because when it's done with the substitution, it will look for a file of that name that the substitution creates.