# SSH key *.pem get fingerprint?

Tags: bash, ssh

I want to have a fingerprint of my SSH key file which is a private key (PEM file).

I tried following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2635360/ssh-keygen-accepting-stdin) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6749128/store-output-of-sed-into-a-variable) advice:

```
key=$(ssh-keygen -yf lony.pem) | echo $key | ssh-keygen -lf /dev/stdin <<<"$key"
```

Resulting int this error:

> /dev/stdin is not a public key file.

The key file looks like:

> -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- 
>   .. 
>   -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

How can I get the fingerprint?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several problems with this command pipeline:

```
key=$(ssh-keygen -yf lony.pem) | echo $key | 
ssh-keygen -lf /dev/stdin <<<"$key"
```

First, it's not clear why you're trying to pipe (`|`) the stdout of your assignment statement to the `echo` statement. The first doesn't produce any output, and the second doesn't consume any input.  In the third component, you are piping the stdout from the `echo` command to stdin of the `ssh-keygen`...where you are *also* redirecting stdin using the `<<<` operator.

The easiest way to get the fingerprint from a private key file is just to run:

```
ssh-keygen -lf /path/to/privatekey.pem
```

For example, if we generate a private key:

```
bash-4.3$ ssh-keygen -f testkey -N ''
```

We can then compare the output of this:

```
bash-4.3$ ssh-keygen -lf testkey
2048 SHA256:beF471z86giH7cV49TduNVFD949UXzT+jHxgu+99gmM lars@myhost (RSA)
```

To this:

```
bash-4.3$ ssh-keygen -yf testkey | ssh-keygen -lf /dev/stdin
2048 SHA256:beF471z86giH7cV49TduNVFD949UXzT+jHxgu+99gmM no comment (RSA)
```

And see that we get the same fingerprint from both commands.

Comment: Thanks you are right! I just wanted the fingerprint from the public key. Problem is your last command always results in"/dev/stdin is not a public key file."

Comment: Could it be that AWS is using another fingerprinting method? Using your first method is returning another hash as AWS does :(

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/603982/why-does-my-openssh-key-fingerprint-not-match-the-aws-ec2-console-keypair-finger That solved it

Answer (score -1):

**WITH AWK PIPE (no spaces in "passphrase comment" only)**

```
bash-4.3$ ssh-keygen -lf sshkey | awk -F " " '{print $2" "$3}'
```

> SHA256:beF471z86giH7cV49TduNVFD949UXzT+jHxgu+99gmM user1sshkey